# Sql left join with 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a problem with left join i have 2 tables. Table A:

```
Itemid InventlocationID
10001    200
10001    301
10001    302
```

And table B

```
ItemId InventLocationID ItemOption
10001    200               A
10001    301               B
```

I want to get the following result

```
Itemid InventlocationID ItemOption
10001    200                A
10001    301                B
10001    302               null
```

I use left join:

```
SELECT a.itemid,a.inventlocationid,b.ItemOption
FROM  a
left  join b
on (a.ItemID = b.ITEMID and a.InventLocationid = b.INVENTLOCATIONID)
```

and the result i get is:

```
Itemid InventlocationID Itemoption
10001    200                A
10001    301                B
```

Any ideas how can i achieve the result i want?
Edit : tables a and b have more records

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting that result.  You've written the query correctly.  Is this *exactly* how you have your query?

Comment: I WANT to get this result( but i dont get it):Itemid InventlocationID ItemOption
10001    200                A
10001    301                B
10001    302               null

Comment: My guess is you're using a where clause that you didn't include in the question.  If the WHERE clause references a column in table B, it will not return those rows.  I've made this mistake before and am planning to make it again in the future.

Comment: To add to what @JohnPasquet said, please read this: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: hehe, you guys were right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when you have a WHERE clause that references a column in the LEFT JOIN.  They key point is to use only columns from the first table -- not the one that is LEFT/OUTER joined.

You could still use ans ISNULL() or an OR (col == null) if you needed to.

(giving you an answer instead of a comment)

Answer (score 2):

Your query works fine. (Check your data)

> ```
> create table tablea (Itemid int,  InventlocationID int);
> insert into tablea values
> (10001,    200),
> (10001,    301),
> (10001,    302);
>
> create table tableb (ItemId int, InventLocationID int, ItemOption char(1));
> insert into tableb values
> (10001,    200,               'A'),
> (10001,    301,               'B');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select    a.ItemId, a.InventlocationID, b.ItemOPtion
> from      tableA a
> left join tableB b
> on        a.itemId = b.ItemId
> and       a.InventlocationID = b.InventlocationID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ItemId | InventlocationID | ItemOPtion
> -----: | ---------------: | :---------
>  10001 |              200 | A         
>  10001 |              301 | B         
>  10001 |              302 | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8cf88fdd05eb64bb664f9d4a4ecff67f)*